# How do I create a search over a cell range, of multiple values, returning multiple results (per match) in once cell

Tags: excel, search

I want to run a search over a range of cells and check if they contain a combination of specific numbers, even better if taken from the string contained in the cell within the same range. i.e: I want to check if cells B2:B16 contain both 1 and 2.

I then want to take the values from column A, in the rows which matched the search, and return them to a single cell in column C.

In the example shown n, cell C2 lists all the ID numbers from Column A from rows, which correspond to the cells in column B which contain a string with the number "1". (Bonus for the one who also adds an automation on extracting the number from each cell's string).

The job gets trickier when descending down the cells in column B, as the search has to find string with a combination of several numbers (AND rule).
The only way I managed to get the results in cell C2 is by using a very long combination of:IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH, which is not practical, as I need to manually adjust it for each cell in Column C.

The formula is as follows:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B3,14)),A3," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B4,14)),A4," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B5,14)),A5," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B6,14)),A6," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B7,14)),A7," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B8,14)),A8," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B9,14)),A9," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B10,14)),A10," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B11,14)),A11," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B12,14)),A12," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B13,14)),A13," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B14,14)),A14," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B15,14)),A15," ")&IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D2,B16,14)),A16," ")
```

Any idea on how I can make this whole operation more efficient?

[image]

Comment: You should make use of VBA, or maybe a pivot table. But I'm unsure about the latter. I don't use them that often, but they are more powerfull then you'd think. Also, you might want to add an helper column with only the numbers, that usually makes things easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function:

```
Function GetMatches(InputCell As Range, SearchRange As Range) As String

Dim MyArray() As Variant
Dim Res As String
Dim X As Long, Y As Long, Z As Long
Dim CL As Range

'Get numbers from target cell
Y = 0
For X = 1 To Len(InputCell.Value)
    If Mid(InputCell.Value, X, 1) >= "0" And Mid(InputCell.Value, X, 1) <= "9" Then
        Y = Y + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyArray(Y)
        MyArray(Y) = Mid(InputCell.Value, X, 1)
    End If
Next X

'Loop through all cells in specified range
For Each CL In SearchRange
    For Z = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        If InStr(1, CL.Value, MyArray(Z)) = 0 Then GoTo 1
    Next Z
    If CL.Row <> InputCell.Row Then Res = Res & CL.Offset(0,-1).value & " "    
1: Next CL

GetMatches = Res

End Function
```

Call in your sheet by adding this formula in cell `C2`: `=GetMatches(B2,$B$2:$B$16)` and drag down.

For your second request you could do it like so:

```
Function GetMatches2(InputCell As Range, SearchRange As Range) As String

Dim MyArray() As String
Dim Res As String, Inp As String
Dim X As Long, Y As Long, Z As Long
Dim CL As Range

'Get codes from inputcell
MyArray = Split(Replace(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Right(InputCell, Len(InputCell) - InStr(1, InputCell, "\"))), " and ", "\"), "\")

'Loop through all cells in specified range
For Each CL In SearchRange
    For Z = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)
        Inp = "\" & Replace(Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(Right(CL.Value, Len(CL.Value) - InStr(1, CL.Value, "\"))), " and ", "\")
        If InStr(1, Inp, "\" & MyArray(Z)) = 0 Then GoTo 1
    Next Z
    If CL.Row <> InputCell.Row Then Res = Res & CL.Offset(0, -1).Value & " "
1: Next CL

GetMatches = Res

End Function
```

Call in your sheet by adding this formula in cell `C2`: `=GetMatches2(B2,$B$2:$B$16)` and drag down.

Comment: Wow. This is amazing!
Worked like a charm! Much obliged!

Comment: Hi, @JvdV, how would I adjust this function to perform a search for certain letters in each cell in the search range?

Comment: @user10944008, This sounds like you can just use formula's.

Comment: I'd be at the same dilemma as with the numbers search

Comment: I mean, what how can I adjust your function to work if the values in the "Caption" column change to the following:
Press electrode\nC
Press electrode\nG
Press electrodes\nC and G
Press electrode\nLT
Press electrodes\nC and LT
Press electrodes\nG and LT
Press electrodes\nC, G and LT
Press electrode\nLE
Press electrodes\nC and LE
Press electrodes\nG and LE
Press electrodes\nC, G and LE
Press electrodes\nLE and LT
Press electrodes\nC, LE and LT
Press electrodes\nG, LE and LT
Press electrodes\nC, G, LE and LT
Press electrode\nRT
Press electrodes\nRT and C

and etc.

Comment: I've edited the code but I just wanted to say that this is not a free coding website. Next time try and put effort in to change it yourself. When you hit a problem in your code, that's when you call in the 'troops' on here.